# Reversing title and subtitle in foreign edition

Tags: copyright, translation, titles

I am publishing a book with an American publisher. My contract allows me to make a separate contract with one particular foreign publisher for a translation in his language. That foreign publisher wants to reverse the title and subtitle in the translation. I support that idea. Two questions. Is this legal? Do I need to get permission from my American publisher for this switch?

Answer (score 1):

**It's very common to change titles with new editions of a book.**

Obviously, the title will be translated to a non-English language with this new publisher.  When translating, it's common to change the order of words as well.

Sometimes titles change in different editions for the same language.  *Harry Potter And The Sorcerer's Stone* changed to *Harry Potter And The Philosopher's Stone* when moving from the original British edition to the American one.  *The Psychology of Everyday Things* changed to *The Design of Everyday Things* when going from a hardback to a paperback within the U.S.

If you're worried, the best action is to ask your original publisher.  Or you could simply drop them a line saying "[Publisher] plans to release an edition in [language] by approximately [date] with the title [title]."  If they say "thanks for letting us know" you're good.  If they have an objection, they'll tell you.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the legal wording of "allows me to make a separate contract with one particular foreign publisher" entails.

Do YOU make that contract, legally moslty independent with the foreign publisher? 
Or is your US Publisher still involved in that contract?

[Also I would just call my person from the US publisher and ask them, since it sounds like they have absolutely no problem with this new foreign publisher / actively allowed it]

Comment: Thank you for your input. Helpful. My contract with my American publisher made an exception for foreign rights for one country with whom I had already started negotiations. So that translation contract is between me and the foreign publisher.